# CFRelease on CMSampleBufferRef - Why do I need to call this?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-leaks

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
CMBlockBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CMBlockBufferAppendBufferReference(_sem == 0 ? _buffer0 : _buffer1, buffer, 0, 0, 0);
//if(sampleBuffer)
//    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

Why does this cause a memory leak at the first line (at least that's where Leaks suggests)? I have my assetOutput.shouldAlwaysCopySampleOutput = NO. Here's my understanding of the situation:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
```

This line will create a *reference* to the sample buffer from the assetOutput.

```
CMBlockBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
```

This line will get the CMBlockBuffer from the CMSampleBuffer but will not allocate a new buffer, and the Get method in this case means it is a temporary (autoreleased) buffer

```
CMBlockBufferAppendBufferReference(_sem == 0 ? _buffer0 : _buffer1, buffer, 0, 0, 0);
```

This line will append the *reference* of the CMBlockBuffer created above, to the selected global-scope buffer. It will not copy any memory blocks.

So in none of these three lines do I allocate any memory nor do I copy any memory, it's all references. I don't understand where the leak is coming from. I tried adding the commented out lines and it still seems to leak (although fewer times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alwaysCopiesSampleData` is not about memory management.  It is only about whether you are scribbling on the original sample buffer or a clone of the original.  It is somewhat unfortunately named.

`copyNextSampleBuffer` follows the create rule and as such, should be released when you are done with it.  It creates a reference with a retain count of at least 1.

The Create Rule:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029

Apple's doc links tend to change, but if the above link dies, just google "The Create Rule"

Comment: ah, thanks for clearing up the alwaysCopiesSampleData property. That was the mistake in my thinking!

Comment: Actually, there's still one thing I don't understand:

If CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer returns a temporary reference, and CMBlockBufferAppendBufferReference only appends the reference (and doesn't copy the data), shouldn't CFRelease(sampleBuffer) crash the app the minute I try to read from the buffer that was appended to?

Answer (score 2):

Core Foundation data structures follows the same ownership rules as Foundation objects.

The rules are pretty simple - whatewer you create (or get the ownership by some other way), you have to destroy. If some other method wants to work with the same structure/object, it has to ask for the ownership and thus preventing the destruction.

Taking ownership = "create" / "retain"
Releasing ownership ("destruction") = "release"

In your sample code, you have created a structure using `copyNextSampleBuffer`. That means, you have to also destroy it using `CFRelease`.

(Note that with ARC you don't actually see the `retain` and `release` calls but with Core Foundation, you have to use them explicitely).